# Using expandable headerview in Swift3

Tags: ios, json, swift3

I have tried several times but no luck. I made it expandable with Swift3 and I can get the JSON data but when parsing data to expandable tableview that appear only one. Here's my coding I use:

Here JSON:

```
"project": [
        {
            "bu_name": "IT and Digital Ecosystem Solution Delivery",
            "project_list": [
                {
                    "project_id": 8791520,
                    "project_name": "MobApps Radio"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "bu_name": "Business Solution, Delivery & MO",
            "project_list": [
                {
                    "project_id": 8791392,
                    "project_name": "Research and Development Hololens (Augmented Virtual Reality)"
                },
                {
                    "project_id": 8790857,
                    "project_name": "Application Development for Probis Digital Service”
                },
                {
                    "project_id": 8436483,
                    "project_name": "Non Project - Application DMO"
                },
                {
                    "project_id": 8179950,
                    "project_name": "Release Quality Improvement"
                },
                {
                    "project_id": 7548089,
                    "project_name": "Application Development"                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Here coding get JSON data:

```
var perfArrProjectId = [String]()
var perfArrProjectName = [String]()
var namabu = ""

    if let itemProject = jsonData?["project"] as? NSArray {
        for i in 0..<itemProject.count {
            if let obj = itemProject[i] as? NSDictionary {
               let stringBU = obj.makeIterator().next()
                namabu = stringBU?.value as! String
                print("BU Name: \(namabu)")
                                        
                let buName2 = obj["bu_name"] as! String                     
                 perfArrBuName.append(buName2)
                                        
                 guard let projectList = obj["project_list"] as? [[String: Any]] else {return}
                                        
                 for list in projectList {
                     let projectId = list["project_id"] as! Int
                     let projectName = list["project_name"] as! String
                                            
                                            
                     perfArrProjectId.append(String(projectId))
                      perfArrProjectName.append(projectName)
    
                    print("_Project ID: \(projectId) \n_Project Name: \(projectName) \n”)
    
                        listPerformances = [
ModelPerformances(bussines: namaBU, projectid: perfArrProjectId, projectName: perfArrProjectName expand: false)
]
                        
                      }
                  }
             }
        }
```

Here output:

```
BU Name: IT and Digital Solution Delivery
__Project ID: 8791520 
__Project Name: MobApps Radio 

BU Name: Business Solution, Delivery & MO
__Project ID: 8791392 
__Project Name: Research and Development (Augmented Virtual Reality) 

__Project ID: 8790857 
__Project Name: Application Development for Digital 

__Project ID: 8436483 
__Project Name: Non Project - Application DMO

__Project ID: 8179950 
__Project Name: Release Quality Improvement Program 

__Project ID: 7548089 
__Project Name: Application Development
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem, you dont know how many submenu item you have.

change them

```
 perfArrProjectId.append(String(projectId))
 perfArrProjectName.append(projectName)
```

with

```
 perfArrProjectId[[String]]
 perfArrProjectName[[String]]

 inside the first for

 perfArrProjectId.append([String]())
 perfArrProjectName.append([String]())

 second for

 perfArrProjectId[i].append(String(projectId))
 perfArrProjectName[i].append(projectName)
```

Comment: I have changed as you are coding but there is a fatal error: Index out of range and error are in perfArrProjectName [i] .append (projectName)

Comment: here model:  class ModelPerformances {
    var bussines: String
    var projectId: [String]
    var projectName: [String]
    var expand: Bool
    
    init(bussines: String, projectId: [String], projectName: [String], expand: Bool) {
        self.bussines = bussines
        self.projectId = projectId
        self.projectName = projectName
        self.expand = expand
    }
}

Comment: i change too listPerformances = [
                                ModelPerformances(bussines: namabu, project: perfArrProjectName[i], progress: perfArrProjectComplete[i], status: perfArrProjectStatus[i], expand: false)
                            ]

Comment: Thank for answer but I've tried but the result is still the same

Comment: his case is equal to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46590036/parsing-json-to-expandcollapse-costum-headerview-in-swift-3